# Lifetime of lambda c++

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17

I have the following situations and trying to understand the scope of the lambdas

```
 std::future<void> thread_run;
 void run(Someclass& dbserver){
     thread_run = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]{ 
                      dbserver.m_com.run([&dbserver]() { 
                         // implement another nested lambda for the m_com.run method. Does this get destroyed when the main thread leaves the run method. 
                      }
                  }
 }

  class dbserver{ 
     Com m_com;
   }

  class Com{
     template<typename F>
     void run(F&& func){ // do some stuff here}
  
   }
```

So we launch a thread with its main lambda function. I am guessing the `std::async` will take care of the scope of that main lambda function. However, in my application I also invoke a function within the main lambda. That function also requires a lambda.

My question is whether the nested lambda actually has a local scope and therefore could be leading to undefined behaviour or did I miss something that will make it work.

Comment: Names have scope, objects have lifetime. There are no special lifetime rules for lambdas - they are just objects - so you need to be normally careful about references.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "scope" for the lambda. I *think* you are worried about the *life-time* issue regarding the `dbserver` object?

Comment: I also don't understand what it is you are worried about. Can you elaborate? Of course you must make sure that the object referenced by `dbserver` lives as long as the asynchronous call has not finished, but that is true whether there is a nested lambda or not.

Comment: Create the dbserver before the future and let the future go out of scope before dbserver does and you are fine. If you somehow cannot manage that you may need to use a std::shared_ptr Someclass and pass that by value to your lambda to extend the lifetime to that of the thread.

Comment: @pepijnkramer make that an answer

Comment: @user17732522 once my main thread returns from the main run method which happens right after the thread is spawned - I am worried about whether the nested lambda gets destroyed. I am not talking about the lambda that goes as part of the argument to the std::async, but about the lambda that is defined locally within the main lambda

Comment: @ATK The lambda object is only created when the lambda expression is evaluated. It's lifetime is the same as any other temporary object would have in that position.

Comment: Why does your code use `dbserver` for both a parameter name and a class name? That seems needlessly confusing. In a similar vein, why use `run` for both a member function template and a non-member function? Could you choose names that help the reader? And perhaps put your code in a more traditional order (definitions before use)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the dbserver before the future and let the future go out of scope before dbserver and you are fine (the future destructor will synchronize with the end of the thread) . If you somehow cannot manage that you may need to use a `std::shared_ptr<Someclass>` and pass that by value to your lambda to extend the lifetime of the database to that of the thread. (I usually am careful about using std::shared_ptr but I find this is a very good use for it)

Comment: Are you sure about that ? When tthe main thread returns from my main run method, does the "nested" lambda defined within the async api not get destroyed? I am not talking about the main lambda which goes in as part of the arguments to the std::async, but I am talking about lambda defined within that lambda

Comment: Make sure the lambda passed to async is also copied/captured by value (so you don't use the temporary).